# Singleton class implementing an interface

Tags: java, interface, dependencies, singleton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is so bad about Singletons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)

One of the drawbacks of using Singleton, as widely discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)
 stackoverflow question is that they hide the class dependencies in the code. However, we can make a singleton implement an interface while still obeying the two rules of singleton: single instance and global scope. 
Why is Singleton still said to hide dependencies?

Comment: I agree (even if I answered). The problem I see with the present question is that it tend to see SO as a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding dependencies means there is no visible link from your code to the singleton, as the singleton can be called from anywhere. Having the singleton implementing an interface doesn't change the problem.